# Route user to correct area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-areas

When a user logs in. I'm looking for a way to route a user to the correct area based on their role in identity.

I've tried:

- You have the default controller that you can redirect to that area `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" });`,
  but I have multiple roles.
- Add a rewrite option in the StartUp Configure method. Which works in the beginning, but if you have a link to another area - it doesn't work.
- On the default controller I created a view. Added some razor `@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin")) else if()`. Then used `<text>`and `<script>` tags in between the if statements to call a function that would redirect the user. It didn't provide an error, just didn't work. I figured it wouldn't, but... trying to think outside the box

Thanks ahead for the ideas!

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use some if statements (or switch) with your first approach to redirect to the appropriate area?

Comment: @Ben I could, but i'd need to find a way to get the current user's role, because `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` doesn't work inside a method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the ASP.Net MVC Login Redirect based on role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865905/how-can-i-change-the-asp-net-mvc-login-redirect-based-on-role)

Comment: ^ this will help solve your problem. It also explains why your call to `User.IsInRole` directly after sign in didn't work. You could also forward all sign ins to a secondary Action that then (a) get's the user's roles and (b) uses an IF/Switch to hierarchically drill through the roles redirecting to the relevant final View.

Comment: @ShahzadHassan @scgough Thanks for the feedback. I have a `[Authorize]` on the default controller, I would think that it would show the view until authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using asp.net core identity,in controller, you could directly use `var isInRole = User.IsInRole("Admin")` to check whether current user has an `Admin` role.

Or use `UserManager` to get current user and all his roles:

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestView()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    var matchingvalues = roles.SingleOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals("Admin"));
    if(matchingvalues != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" });
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about this route (it was a 15 hour day). I just changed the IdentityUser model to use my custom one (added other properties) and it works.